# In 'C' How can I keep track of value of a variable

Tags: c, variables

I am beginner in c. how can i keep track of for example years until some population reach some given data. This is my poor level code.

```
// TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
for (int years = 0; s == e; years++)
while (s == e) // s is starting size and e is ending size
    {
        s = s + (s / 3) - (s /4);
    }
```

I don't even know how to aproach this problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve, and what the code does that differs from what you expect. That would be very helpful.

Comment: By giving your variables meaningful names we could maybe guess what you're trying to achieve. What are `s ` and `e`? What is the problem statement in plain english? Read this: [ask], then [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Hint: think about why `s == e` is a very bad idea?

Comment: To keep track of a value you use a thing called a *variable*.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int population = 40;   // initial population
  int threashold = 500;
  int years = 0;

  while (population < threashold)
  {
    population = population + (population / 3) - (population / 4);
    years = years + 1;
    printf("year: %d, population: %d\n", years, population);
  }
}
```

The code is pretty self explaining.

A nice exercise for you would be to show the increase in population each year, for example like this:

```
year: 1, population: 43, increase: 3
year: 2, population: 47, increase: 4
year: 3, population: 51, increase: 4
year: 4, population: 56, increase: 5
year: 5, population: 60, increase: 4
year: 6, population: 65, increase: 5
...
```

Another question for you: find out why the increase from 3rd to 4th year is 5 and the increase from 4th to 5th year is 4 again (less than 5)?